# Lucene 4.9: Create temporary Directory with Documents

Tags: apache, lucene, directory, temporary

I have a FSDirectory, let's call it NORMAL, which already contains many indexed Document instances. Now, I want to create a temporary Index, i.e., RAMDirectory and IndexReader / IndexSearcher, that contains a subset of the previously indexed Documents (let's call this directory TEMP).

I am wondering what's the best way to do that. While indexing data into NORMAL I use an Analyzer that performs stemming on the tokens (EnglishAnalyzer); also not all of the fields are actually stored, i.e., some of them are only indexed but their value is not stored within the Directory NORMAL. That's fine so far.

1. However, if I now take a subset of such documents, which I later on read with an IndexReader, and I readd them to the TEMP Directory, is it appropriate for example to use also EnglishAnalyzer or does it cause re-stemming of already stemmed tokens?
2. And, if a field is not stored at all, I suppose it cannot be used for adding it to TEMP right?

Answer (score 1):

- 1:  It is appropriate to re-analyze.  The stored representation of the field is not stemmed, tokenized, or anything else.  It's just the raw data.
- 2:  Generally, that's right.  If a field is not stored, you can't get it out.  Technically, you might be able to reconstruct a lossy version of the field, if the right parameters are set when indexing, and if you are tenacious.  Wouldn't recommend it when you could just store the field, of course.

This reads a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though.  Are you sure there isn't an easier way to do whatever it is you are trying to do?  Perhaps by [filtering](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2009/02/filtering-a-lucene-search.html)?

Comment: I'm asking this because I have many documents in the Directory NORMAL, and now I need to get the total term frequency for only those terms, that occur in a subset of documents (selected by the user). So this could be an XY problem, I don't know, but I think that creating another, temporary Directory with this subset of documents is one way to go, isn't it? Thanks!